# Inject DatabaseManager in Repository Class

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I am using Lumen and trying to inject DatabaseManager in Repository Class to run some queries without support of `DB` facade and `Eloquent`.

I have tried following...

```
use Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager;

    class Myclass
    {
        public function __construct(DatabaseManager $database)
        {
            $this->db = $database;
        }

      public function blah()
      {
        $this->db->connection()->table('table')->select('*');
      }
    }
```

But i am getting following error...

```
BindingResolutionException in Container.php line 823:
Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $app ]] in class Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager
```

What is the best way to do this. Please suggest. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to inject `DatabaseManager` then you need to bind it to container so that it knows how to instantiate it:

```
$app->alias('db', 'Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager');
```

Lumen by default does not do it, so you have to do it manually somewhere in your bootstrap code. This tells IoC to resolve `Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager` using `db` via service locator.

Alternatively you could have done the following:

```
app()->make('db');
```